# Google API/OAuth - How to use support@example.com email address for "Branding Information"?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-oauth

I'm setting up Google+ based login (OAuth2) to my website to allow people to login with their existing Google accounts (gmail, etc).

The login piece all works fine but the email address that gets displayed for the "Branding Information" is my personal email address (i.e. `me@example.com`). I'd like it to be `support@example.com` which is setup as a alias pointing to mine and a couple other accounts. We use Google Apps for email with a custom domain (not gmail). It's not currently it's own account.

I can edit the title and logo but there is no option to change the email address. How can I change the email to be `support@example.com`?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of where you see your email address?

Answer (score 10):

To change your support email address for Branding Information, start by logging on using the current address.

1. Add the correct address to the member list.
2. Using the 'Team' menu on the right, grant your other email address access rights. I granted 'is owner' but other options might work. You can have multiple owners.
3. Then, sign in to the API console with your other account (the support email you just added) and go to API Access.
4. Click on 'edit branding information' to show the details.
5. Finally, click next to your support email, where it says 'set to yourself' (or something along this line).

Comment: I have been searching everywhere on how to do this.  Thanks for the anwser.

Comment: I have the same problem but since 9 years have passed I think the interface may have changed. Could you tell me where is the "member list", "Team menu" or "edit branding information" that you mention? I can't find them.