# I can't use alias email as user support email in Google consent auth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

The "user support email" field in Google Oauth Consent does not allow me to enter an alias.

Initially, it shows me only my email (name@company.com).

[image]

I can add any other email in the IAM section successfully, except if the email is an alias. If the email is an alias (eg: support@company.com), when I add the new user in IAM it detects it as the primary email.

How can I use my G Workspace email alias on the consent screen?

I've found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842625/google-api-oauth-how-to-use-supportexample-com-email-address-for-branding-in), but it's 9 years old and I can't find any of the sections mentioned in the answer.

There is also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105894/how-to-change-google-consent-screen-email), which explains how to add a new email. But again, the answer is useless if you want to use an alias of the same email. The reason is that when the alias is entered in IAM, it detects it as the primary mail

Comment: Create an actual Workspace email account to use.

Comment: check the answer from this post about changing [Google consent screen email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105894/how-to-change-google-consent-screen-email) if this help.

Comment: @JohnHanley if what you mean is that I add the alias as a different user in my G Workspace, that is not a solution because (1) I must unnecessarily pay for an additional user and (2) I am "faking" what in it's actually an alias.

Comment: @JonB I had already seen that post, which does not solve my problem. The answers indicate how to add an additional email that is not an alias. I just updated my post highlighting again that adding the alias as an IAM user is not possible, because it makes it the main email.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Did you manage to resolve it and assign an alias as a contact email?

Comment: No I couldn't solve it. Unfortunately SO marked this question as repeated when I explicitly explained why it's different :(

Comment: You have been given the answer. You do not want to implement the answer because you do not want to pay for services. Stack Overflow is a programming site. Your issues with vendor policy are off-topic. Either use the service under their terms or choose a different service. No matter what you decide it is off-topic here.