# I can add a different email, but I can't use alias email as user support email in Google consent auth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

## NOTE:

I already asked this question and it was closed because it is supposedly a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105894/how-to-change-google-consent-screen-email). I made an edit explaining the difference but it was never revised. The difference with that post is that it explains how to add a **NEW** email. But that answer is useless if you want to use an **alias of the same email**. The reason is that when the alias is entered in IAM, it detects it as the primary mail.

Then there's [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842625/google-api-oauth-how-to-use-supportexample-com-email-address-for-branding-in), but it's 9 years old and I can't find any of the sections mentioned in the answer. Probably changed the interface.

## Question

The "user support email" field in Google Oauth Consent does not allow me to enter an alias.

Initially, it shows me only my email (name@company.com).
[image]

I can add any other email in the IAM section successfully, except if the email is an alias. If the email is an alias (eg: support@company.com), when I add the new user in IAM it detects it as the primary email.

How can I use my G Workspace email alias on the consent screen?

Comment: Did you attempt following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72893341/16923081)?

Comment: Yes. I can use myname@domain.com instead of myname@gmail.com, as explained there. What I can't do is use alias@domain.com. When I add it, it ignores the alias and puts the main email.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on [Programmatically creating OAuth clients for IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients#setup-oauth):

> `supportEmail`: The support email displayed on the OAuth consent screen. This email address can either be a user's address or a Google Groups alias. While service accounts also have an email address, they are not actual valid email addresses, and cannot be used when creating a brand. However, a service account can be the owner of a Google Group. Either create a new Google Group or configure an existing group and set the desired service account as an owner of the group.

So in this case, the support email can be only your primary address, or the email of a Google Group.

A workaround would be to create a Google Group with the support email you want and provide this, though this only works if the alias you want is part of your domain.

Alternatively, you can file a feature request for this on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1120253&template=1629995)

Comment: I have created a Google group with another alternative email, but I have not been able to use the alias since an unused email is required. I'm surprised you can't use an alias, since they're meant for exactly this kind of situation. Thanks for your answer.